# Is Potentiometer a variable resistor or a measuring instrument?

Tags: electric-circuits, terminology, electrical-resistance, instrument

I have used Potentiometers many times, and what I understood is that it is a variable resistor. However, my Physics teacher says that he is SURE a potentiometer is used to measure stuff, and is NOT a variable resistor. Then why are these variable resistors called Potentiometers? I asked him that, and he said nobody calls variable resistors potentiometers, and I must be the only one. Can somebody please clear my confusion over this topic?

Comment: There is indeed [a measuring instrument called a potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer_(measuring_instrument)) as well as [the variable resistor called a potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer). You and your teacher are talking about two different things.

Comment: Looks like there are two definitions for "potentiometer" (see link below), and your teacher was using definition #1 and you were using definition #2. That's OK. I was only aware of definition #2, too. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/potentiometer

Comment: General tip: Google keywords before asking.